# Django REST Framework: URLs without PK

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework with the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`

**serializer.py:**

```py
class ReportTypesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ReportType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportTypesSerializer
```

**api.py:**

```py
class ReportTypesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ReportType
        fields = ('name', 'uuid', 'active', )
```

Now the API works, but the hyperlinks have the `pk` within their URLs, such as: http://localhost:8000/api/reporttypes/1/

I would like to map the objects via the UUID field (which the model provides) rather than the internal PK. I know I could change the primary key to the UUID field, but I've read that would cause other issues, such as decreased performance.

Is there a way I can reference the objects via the UUID, but still internally use the default pk (id)?

Answer (score 4):

This is what you should do:

```
class ReportTypesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ReportType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportTypesSerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
```

This tells DRF that you are using the uuid field for lookups and not the pk which is the default

Comment: This worked with an additional condition, it seemed that "url" had to be omitted from the `fields` meta property.

Answer (score 0):

For your url config use slug instead pk:

```
path(_('api')+'/<slug:slug>/', app.api_view, name='api'),
```

For your model/serializer make sure it contains both uuid and id